# Error in plotting: OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or turtle

Tags: netlogo

I am studying a model where children play with some toys.

The characteristics of the toys are included in `attribute1`. I had to create a new variable, `attribute1_b`, as I wanted to have initially the same original value for the neighbours in order to subtract a small quantity `m`. I would like to plot the new value of `attribute1` to study how it changes through time, respect of `fun2` (i.e. `1- (attribute1-m)`), but unfortunately I have found difficulties in defining `fun2` (`global, children-own, and/or toys-own`).

After plotting

```
ask children [plotxy [attribute1] of picked_toy fun2]
```

I have got the following error message:

> Runtime Error: OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or turtle but
>   good the number 0 instead

Could you please tell me what the message is referring to and how to fix it?
It is important for me to consider the attribute1 related to the `picked_toy`, as its value can be equal to `attribute1` (as in `myself`) or `attribute1 - m` (as in `ask link-neighbors`).

The code that I am using for building the model is the following

```
globals [
      this-toy
      attribute1_b
    ]

breed [children child]
breed [toys toy]

children-own [
  bag

  fun1
  fun2
  attribute1
  picked_toy
]

toys-own[
  fun1
  attribute1
  m_children
]
```

One procedure, `to proc1`, includes the definition of attribute1 and `fun1` as follows:

```
if breed = children[
          set selected children

          hatch-toys 1 [
            set m_children selected
            set attribute1 random-float 1
            set attribute1_b attribute1
            set fun1 (1 - attribute1)

            set this-toy self

            ask myself [
              set bag fput this-toy bag
            ]
         ]
                ask link-neighbors [
                   let m random-float 0.01
                   set attribute1 attribute1_b - m

                   set bag fput this-toy bag
               ]
            ]
```

Another one,`to proc2`, should include the definition of `fun2`:

```
if breed = children [
        set picked_toy max-one-of turtle-set bag [attribute1]
        set fun2 (1 - [attribute1] of picked_toy)
        set bag fput picked_toy bag
]
```

UPDATE: I am also getting the following error message (because of `max-one-of turtle-set`):

> List inputs to TURTLE-SET must only contain turtle or turtle agentset
>   elements. The list [(toy 20) 0] contained 0 which is NOT a turtle or
>   turtle agentset.

I cannot understand where `0` comes from...

All comments and clarification are more than welcome.  Thanks

Comment: Hi JenB. `picked_toy` was defined in `children_own` when I got the error.

Comment: I am showing you the actual code that has generated the error (s). My apologies, but I only forgot to include the `picked_toy` in the `children-own` when I deleted the other variables that were not relevant for this question. Running the code several times, without any change from what I wrote in the question, I also got the error on the bottom of the question. But this is the actual code that I am using and I have referred to since when I published this question

Comment: Then I can't understand how you got this error. The code has 'picked-toy' in two places - as a global variable and a turtle variable, but both are commented out so you should be getting an error that 'picked-toy' does not exist to `set`. You need to do some basic debugging to try and isolate your problem a bit more. In your last section of code, try printing 'bag' before the first line and see if it contains what you think, then print 'picked-toy' after it's selected, then print 'attribute1' of picked toy.

Comment: It works correctly (but there is the problem with the turtle-set for max-one-of) when I print `bag` before and after adding items. Also the items are selected ini the right way and it seems ok when I print `print (word "Toy " picked_toy " has the highest attribute = " [attribute1] of picked_toy)`. However, when I plot `ask children [plotxy [attribute1] of picked_toy fun2]` I get the error. And I cannot understand the reason why, as in the print it correctly reads the value of `[attribute1] of picked_toy`. Could it be because of the fun2?

Comment: Both `picked_toy` and `fun2` are commented out in my question as I do not know where I should define them in order to make the code (plot) working

Comment: I think the error is in defining `set picked_toy max-one-of turtle-set bag [attribute1]` because of the `turtle-set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 'picked_toy' should be a turtle attribute so uncomment it there and delete it from the global variables. A global variable is something that is the same for every agent in your model. Clearly, each child has its own toy, so that needs to be an agent variable. This is what agent variables do - each agent has its own copy (which can be different or the same as those of other agents). You need to get this concept clear if you want to make any progress in NetLogo and I suggest redoing some tutorials.

This line `set picked_toy max-one-of turtle-set bag [attribute1]` doesn't really make sense. The variable 'bag' is a list. The primitive `max-one-of` applies to an agentset. I think you have tried to use `turtle-set` to convert the list to an agentset, but that won't work. The correct way to turn a list of turtles into an agentset is:

```
turtles with [member? self listname]
```

Does your code work if you have:

```
set picked_toy max-one-of (children with [member? self bag]) [attribute1]
```

As I have mentioned in responses to some of your other questions, unless you have a good reason to use lists (like needing to keep the order, or having multiple copies), it is generally better to use agentsets because they are easier to work with, particularly for beginners.

Comment: `turtle-set` actually is the best way to convert a list of turtles into an agentset. But, I agree it's usually better to avoid having a list of turtles in the first place.

Comment: interesting. i thought `turtle-set` did the conversion, but when I looked it up, I got that code directly from the user's guide. I probably forgot to check which NetLogo version I was looking at!