# How to include more breeds in max-one-of and plot the highest value found and its distribution

Tags: netlogo

I am using lists to build a model. I have three breeds, but only two of them  have their own lists where to collect items created (and that should create items). 
I would like to select a random turtle and find the item with highest attribute into its bag. Then I would like to plot the attribute and its distribution as follows:

```
plotxy attribute1 fun2
```

where `attribute1` is the attribute defined within the `ask link-neighbors`:

```
set attribute1 attribute1_b - m
```

and `fun2` should be defined as `set fun2 (1 - [attribute1])` `where` attribute1 should be the attribute of the 'selected' item with highest attribute in the bag.

Since I have three breeds involved in this part of code, `children`, `infants` and `toy`, respectively, but I would like to consider to plot only attributes generated by `children` and `infants`, I would like to ask you how to define the toy with highest attribute in the bag, then how to plot it for both `children` and `infants`.
From my previous question [Error in plotting: OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220098/error-in-plotting-of-expected-input-to-be-a-turtle-agentset-or-turtle/59234890#59234890)
 I received this answer:

```
set picked_toy max-one-of (children with [member? self bag]) [attribute1]
```

but in this current case the maximum could be not only of `children`, but also of `infants`.
I tried to write:

```
set picked_toy max-one-of (children with [member? self bag] and infants with[member? self bag] [attribute1]
```

but I got the following error:

> AND expected this input to be a TRUE/FALSE, but got an agentset
>   instead

I am a self-taught, I read a lot of material on the websites, but sometimes I cannot find what I would like to look for. I make mistakes, a lot of mistakes, but probably this is also a good way to learn (and to keep in mind to avoid to repeat the same). 
I hope you can understand and try to help me to figure out with this new issue. Thanks.

Comment: Why is `bag` a list and not an agentset? Also, it's peculiar that the breed is named `infant`, why isn't it named `infants`, plural?

Comment: my fault. It is `infants` (plural), not `infant` (I copied and pasted infant in the post). I used a list for bag and not an agentset because I need to consider an ordered collection of agents (`toys`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are combining two agentsets (a subset of children and a subset of infants) with the keyword `and`, but `and` is reserved for logical operations. To combine two agentsets, we use the `turtle-set` primitive as so.

```
set picked_toy max-one-of ((turtle-set children with [member? self bag] infants with[member? self bag])) [attribute1]
```

The () around `turtle-set` is required because we are giving it more than one argument.
(I haven't looked at the rest of your code, just this line.)  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Charles. It works well!!

Comment: An alternative approach, unless I misunderstand something, would be `(turtle-set bag) with [is-child? self or is-infant? self]`. Assuming `bag` is typically small, this will be more efficient than iterating through all children and all infants in order to construct the result.

Comment: Thank you so much, Seth. It expects 2 inputs. Furthermore, after running a few times, when I print the value of `picked_toy` I am getting the value `nobody`. Do you know why?

Comment: Please open a new question.

Comment: Thank @SethTisue. Please find the new question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345972/turtle-nobody-and-elements-0-in-a-list)